# Использование параметра, переданного скрипту оболочки

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Скрипт 6.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#1 - output file name
#2 - the target folder
#3 - extension

find $2 -name '*.$3' > $1
```

Вызванный find из терминала работает

```
find /media/ubuntu -name '*.txt' > txtFile.txt
```

В скрипте find не работает, записывает в файл 0 байт:

```
6.sh txtFiles.txt /media/ubuntu txt
```

Comment: вероятно, стоит заменить `'*.$3'` на `\*.$3`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Помогло, обращу внимание, что надо убрать кавычки, я сначала просто попробовал экранировать \*

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо) Можете дать ответ, либо я сам отвечу через какое-то время, чтобы без ответа не лежал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[согласно стандарту posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02), внутри строки, заключённой в «одинарные» кавычки <kbd>'</kbd>, сохраняется «буквальное» значение каждого символа.

и, например, вместо `$3` **не** подставляется значение третьего параметра, переданного скрипту: строка используется «как есть».

можно заменить «одинарные» кавычки на «двойные» <kbd>"</kbd>:

```
$ ... "*.$3" ...
```

а можно и вообще убрать кавычки, но тогда, во избежание интерпретации оболочкой получившегося выражения `*xyz` как [регулярного для подстановки имён файлов/каталогов](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03), надо «экранировать» мета-символ <kbd>*</kbd>:

```
$ ... \*.$3 ...
```

Comment: мне кажется, или одинарная кавычка какая-то не такая…

Comment: `set -f` для предотвращения glob. `man sh`.