# Почему не запускается скрипт на стороннем ПК?

Tags: bash, ssh, vesta

Если я захожу под ssh

```
ssh $connect
```

а потом в ручную ввожу такую команду то все работает

```
bash /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-web-domain $VESTACP_USER $HOST_NAME
```

но я пишу скрипт *автоматизации* *процессов*

```
ssh $connect "bash /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-web-domain $VESTACP_USER $HOST_NAME" &&
```

и после данной команды которая выполняется в скрипте **script.sh**
я получаю сообщение

```
/usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-web-domain: line 28: /func/main.sh: No such file or directory
```

и в итоге сайт не добавляется ,в чем причина и как это исправить ?

Comment: вероятно, переменные окружения должны браться не локально (как у вас сейчас), а на удалённой стороне. [см., например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629608/178576)

Comment: @aleksandr barakin переменные к удивлению работают ssh $connect "ls -la '$VESTACP_SITES_PATH'"

Comment: и я даже менял права на файл но и это не помогло

Comment: просто сравните вывод `ssh куда-там-надо "echo $VESTACP_USER $HOST_NAME"` и `ssh куда-там-надо 'echo $VESTACP_USER $HOST_NAME'`

Comment: да, а потом посмотрите, что получаете, залогинившись: `echo $VESTACP_USER $HOST_NAME`

Comment: переменные это просто параметры скрипта он и без них бы работал но он не видит эти файлы которые он запускает  /func/main.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все дело было в глобальных переменных их почему то не видно и
мне нужно было их отправить вместе с запросом **ssh**

```
ssh  $connect "export VESTA=/usr/local/vesta/ && bash -cs '/usr/local/vesta/bin/v-add-web-domain $VESTACP_USER $HOST_NAME'" &&
```